# Javascript regex capture giving unexpected results

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to capture all data before the first `_`.  What I have so far is

```js
const regex =  /(.*)(?=_)/g;
var s = "Mike_Jones_Jr";
console.log(s.match(regex));
```

The output is an array `Array ["Mike_Jones","" ]`
What I was expecting was `Mike`

Comment: Well, clearly your expectations were wrong.

Comment: If you just want the text before the first `_` why not `s.split("_")[0]`?

Comment: Trying to improve my understanding of regex.

Comment: `match` is documented as [returning an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Return_value). Why were you expecting a string?

Comment: `s.substring(0, s.indexOf('_'))` would do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var s = "Mike_Jones_Jr";
console.log(s.split('_')[0]);
```

Comment: Your second version fails if `_` is the first character of the string.

Comment: Well that's true, I'll delete the second option

Comment: You could have just fixed it: `/^[^_]*/`.

Answer (score 1):

Use /^[^_]*/

^ looks from the beginning of the string
[^_] negates the _
* gives any number of characters

```js
 const regex =  /^[^_]*/;
 var s = "Mike_Jones_Jr";
 console.log(s.match(regex));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `split`,

***Note:-*** Second parameter is to limit the number of elements in final outptut

```js
var s = "Mike_Jones_Jr";
console.log( s.split('_', 1) );
```

---

If you want to do using regex, you can drop the `g` flag

```js
const regex = /^[^_]*(?=_)/;
var s = "Mike_Jones_Jr";
console.log(s.match(regex));
console.log("_ melpomene  is awesome".match(regex));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a capture group (`(something between parentheses)`) that starts at the beginning of the line (`^`) and is `lazy` (`.*?`), then grab the second item in the matching array.

```js
const regex = /(^.*?)_/s

console.log('Mike_Jones_Jr'.match(regex)[1] || '')

console.log(`Mike
_Jones_Jr`.match(regex)[1] || '')
```

Comment: That fails if there is a newline before the first `_` in the string.

Comment: @melpomene okay fixed by adding the `s` flag

Comment: Note that `s` is not supported in Firefox, IE, or Edge.